# How is the preposition "to" translated into German to express finality?

Tags: preposition

I have a very simple doubt, but I haven't found a satisfying answer yet.

I want to translate this phrase to German:

> I dedicate all my time to study.

But I don't know how the preposition *to* would be translated. It is unknown to me if there is an specific preposition to express finality or if, otherwise, I just have to build a subordinate clause with an infinitive. I thought it could be something like that:

> Ich widme meine ganze Zeit, zu lernen.

Is this correct? If not, how would it be?

Comment: I wouldn't use "widmen" for that, I would simply say "Ich lerne in meiner ganzen Zeit", auch so ist es fehlerhaft, aber verständlich.

Answer (score 7):

The verb *widmen* does not come with a preposition. Your sentence would translate to

> Ich widme meine ganze Zeit dem Studium /dem Lernen.

Answer (score 3):

Languages, even when closely related like English to German, cannot be translated word by word. The closest you can come to literal translation is to proceed construction by construction.

"dedicating s.th. to s.th." is a construction that corresponds to the German construction "[acc] [dat] widmen". That construction doesn't contain a preposition, so it's meaningless to ask "how do I translate the preposition?" - you don't.